# Java Sax Parser - stop processing in EndElementListener

Tags: java, android, xml, sax, saxparser

I'm using android's SAX parser and I wish to stop processing after I have read N elements. Some of the feeds are quite large and can take a while to churn through. How can I stop parsing if certain conditions are met in the EndElementListener for a certain element? Here is my current listener

```
chanItem.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener()  {
    public void end() {
        _items.add(_item);
        if (++_currentItem == _maxElements) {
                //BREAK OUT HERE
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried throwing an exception within end() but EndElementListener doesn't allow for throwing any exceptions. 
Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1345293/965648

Comment: It's actually not Nick - if you have a look you'll see that mine is a bit different because it's using the android.sax parser. I can't throw an exception within the EndElementListener because the interface doesn't support it.

Comment: It appears that it does, I am looking at: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Comment: Ah my mistake, I wasn't looking at the proper one. I'm not sure then, sorry for the confusion.
This was discussed on a different question, although no answer is marked. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3508635/965648

Comment: It's terrible confusing Nick, don't worry about it at all...
I just much rather the way the android.sax parser does it with the ElementListeners so I'd like to continue to use it, assuming I can get  this working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new unchecked exception called "SaxBreakOutException":

```
class SaxBreakOutException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Throw this in your listener:

```
chanItem.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener()  {
    public void end() {
        _items.add(_item);
        if (++_currentItem == _maxElements) {
            throw new SaxBreakOutException();
        }
    }
});
```

And catch it in the code that calls XmLReader.parse():

```
reader.setContentHandler(handler);
try {
    reader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
} catch (SaxBreakOutException allDone) {
}
```

Alternatively, switch to Android's [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) which doesn't require exceptions to break out early.

Comment: Fantastic! I was trying this method myself but was extending SaxException instead of RuntimeException. Thanks Jesse..

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of "Jesse Wilson" is good but in my case I had to preserve de values that returns my parse() method.

```
List<Article> ArticleNews = parser.parse();
```

So i added a boolean value;

```
int countArts;
boolean stopParse;
```

when i had to stop my parser() method, i consume all the listeners with

```
if(stopParse)return;
```

an example:

```
public List<Article> parse(){
        final List<Article> myArticles= new ArrayList<Article>();

        final RootElement root = new RootElement("articles");
        Element nota = root.getChild("article");


        nota.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener(){
            @Override
            public void start(Attributes attributes) {
                Log.i("----------------------------------------", "START Article!\n");
            }
        });

        nota.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){
            public void end() {  

                if(countArts>9){    //only 10 articles!.
                    stopParse=true;
                }               
                countArts++;
                Log.i("----------------------------------------", "END Article!\n");

            }
        });


        nota.getChild(ID).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                if(stopParse)return;
                if(Utilities.isNumeric(body)) {
                    idA = body;
                }
            }
        });
        nota.getChild(CATEGORY).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                if(stopParse)return;
                categoriaA = body;
            }
        });

        nota.getChild(TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                if(stopParse)return;
                tituloA = body;
            }
        });

        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(" *** Exception Xml.parse() ", e.getMessag
        }
        return myArticles;
    }
```